# Apollo gateway gives an error when `@requires` fieldset has an entity which is resolved by two separate clients

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-federation

I have 4 subgraph services namely products, couriers, cargo_service, tax. (Not a real-world example, just playing with graphql federation concepts).

Below is my code for those services.

**products service**

```js
const { ApolloServer} = require("@apollo/server");
const{ startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const {gql} = require("graphql-tag");
const { buildSubgraphSchema } = require("@apollo/subgraph");

const PORT = 4001;

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Product @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID!
        name: String
        price: Float
        courier: Courier @external
        estimatedShippingCharge: Float @requires(fields: "courier {shippingCharge tax} ")
    }
    
    extend type Courier @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID! @external
        shippingCharge: Float @external
        tax: Float @external
    }
    
    extend type Query {
        product(id: ID!): Product
        products: [Product]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Product: {
        __resolveReference(object) {
            return products.find(product => product.id === object.id);
        },
        estimatedShippingCharge(object) {
            console.log(object);
            return object.courier.shippingCharge + object.courier.tax;
        }
    },
    Query: {
        product(_, {id}) {
            return products.find(product => product.id === id);
        },
        products() {
            return products;
        }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: buildSubgraphSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }])
});

startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen:{
        port: PORT
    }
}).then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Products service ready at ${url}`);
});

const products = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Headphones",
        price: 10.99
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Keyboard",
        price: 20.99
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Mouse",
        price: 15.99
    }
]
```

**couriers service**

```js
const { ApolloServer} = require("@apollo/server");
const{ startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const {gql} = require("graphql-tag");
const { buildSubgraphSchema } = require("@apollo/subgraph");

const PORT = 4002;

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Courier @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID!
        name: String
        shippingCharge: Float  @external
        tax: Float @external  
    }
    
    extend type Product @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID!
        courier: Courier
    }
    
    extend type Query {
        courier(id: ID!): Courier
        couriers: [Courier]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Courier: {
        __resolveReference(object) {
            return couriers.find(courier => courier.id === object.id);
        }
    },
    Product: {
        __resolveReference(object) {
            return products.find(product => product.id === object.id);
        }
    },
    Query: {
        courier(_, {id}) {
            return couriers.find(courier => courier.id === id);
        },
        couriers() {
            return couriers;
        }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: buildSubgraphSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }])
});

startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen:{
        port: PORT
    }
}).then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Products service ready at ${url}`);
});

const couriers = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "DHL"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "FedEx"
    }
];

const products = [
    {
        id: "1",
        courier: couriers[0]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        courier: couriers[1]
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        courier: couriers[0]
    }
];
```

**cargo_service**

```js
const { ApolloServer} = require("@apollo/server");
const{ startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const {gql} = require("graphql-tag");
const { buildSubgraphSchema } = require("@apollo/subgraph");

const PORT = 4003;

const typeDefs = gql`
    extend type Courier @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID!
        shippingCharge: Float
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Courier: {
        __resolveReference(object) {
            return shippingCharges.find(shippingCharge => shippingCharge.id === object.id);
        }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: buildSubgraphSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }])
});

startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen:{
        port: PORT
    }
}).then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Products service ready at ${url}`);
});

const shippingCharges = [
    {
        id: "1",
        shippingCharge: 100.99
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        shippingCharge: 200.99
    }
]
```

**tax service**

```js
const { ApolloServer} = require("@apollo/server");
const{ startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const {gql} = require("graphql-tag");
const { buildSubgraphSchema } = require("@apollo/subgraph");

const PORT = 4004;

const typeDefs = gql`
    extend type Courier @key(fields: "id") {
        id: ID!
        tax: Float
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Courier: {
        __resolveReference(object) {
            return taxes.find(tax => tax.id === object.id);
        }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: buildSubgraphSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }])
});

startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen:{
        port: PORT
    }
}).then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Products service ready at ${url}`);
});

const taxes = [
    {
        id: "1",
        tax: 100.99
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        tax: 200.99
    }
];
```

And following is my gateway code.

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require("@apollo/server");
const { ApolloGateway, IntrospectAndCompose } = require("@apollo/gateway");
const { startStandaloneServer } = require("@apollo/server/standalone");
const {serializeQueryPlan} = require('@apollo/query-planner');

const PORT = 4000;

const supergraphSdl = new IntrospectAndCompose({
    subgraphs: [
        { name: "products", url: "http://localhost:4001" },
        { name: "couriers", url: "http://localhost:4002" },
        { name: "cargo_service", url: "http://localhost:4003" },
        { name: "tax", url: "http://localhost:4004" },
    ],
});

const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    supergraphSdl,
    experimental_didResolveQueryPlan: function(options) {
        if (options.requestContext.operationName !== 'IntrospectionQuery') {
            console.log(serializeQueryPlan(options.queryPlan));
        }
    }
});

const server = new ApolloServer({gateway});
startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen:{
        port: PORT
    }
}).then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Products service ready at ${url}`);
});
```

When I queried the following document I get an error.

```
query {
  product(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    price
    courier {
      id
      name
      shippingCharge
      tax
    }
    estimatedShippingCharge
  }
}
```

The error is as below.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "product": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Headphones",
      "price": 10.99,
      "courier": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "DHL",
        "shippingCharge": 100.99,
        "tax": 100.99
      },
      "estimatedShippingCharge": null
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shippingCharge')",
      "path": [
        "product",
        "estimatedShippingCharge"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "stacktrace": [
          "GraphQLError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shippingCharge')",
          "    at downstreamServiceError (D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:514:16)",
          "    at D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:334:59",
          "    at Array.map (<anonymous>)",
          "    at sendOperation (D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:334:44)",
          "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
          "    at async D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:279:49",
          "    at async executeNode (D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:199:17)",
          "    at async executeNode (D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:190:27)",
          "    at async executeNode (D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:173:40)",
          "    at async D:\\poc_ballerina_gateway_requires\\javascript_services\\node_modules\\@apollo\\gateway\\dist\\executeQueryPlan.js:96:35"
        ],
        "serviceName": "products"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since `courier -> shippingCharge` resolved correctly in the query, Why does it complain as undefined when trying to resolve `shippingCharge` as undefined?.
Is there any mistake in my code?.
According to the documentation of `@requires`, they should support this kind of operation.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/entities-advanced/#using-requires-with-object-subfields

PS: Used the Apollo router (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/router/quickstart/) as well. Got same kind of error

Answer (score 0):

What is the object that is logged right before `return object.courier.shippingCharge + object.courier.tax;`? Is it actually a courier? Given your schema I suspect it is just the parent product object with no `courier` field. Your `estimatedShippingCharge` resolver needs to first find the courier for this product before it can get its `shippingCharge` property.

Comment: Isn't that courier field supposed to be added when resolving it by the gateway. Is there any limitation on `@requires` specifications for field argument?. If so can you please provide a reference for it

Comment: Yes, the courier field will be added by the gateway but not necessarily *before* the `estimatedShippingCharge` resolver is called as resolvers are fired asynchronously.

Comment: Yes. I understand. But how can I handle it to get this resolved in proper order? Isn't this need to be handled by the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Opened an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/apollographql/federation/issues/2591) and got the answer there.